# localstorage values resetting after refresh and localstorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

My array and local storage keep resetting after every refresh. I've seen some answers like I need to parse the data and then stringify it. The issue I've faced is I keep getting an error message saying 'local storage is not defined' and an internal server error 500.

I've written the code below

//object

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": 119603782,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
      "name": "react-contextual",
      "full_name": "drcmda/react-contextual",
      "private": false,
     },
{
      "id": 119603782,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
      "name": "react-contextual",
      "full_name": "drcmda/react-contextual",
      "private": false,
     }
```

Getting the object

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-01-10&sort=stars&order=desc"
  );
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

This is my function

```
//trying to keep the values after a page refresh
const favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name')) || [];


//localstorage is not defined 
//define it here 
const storage = typeof window !== 'undefined'? localStorage.getItem('name') : null


 

//check for value then store it in array and to local storage
function checkId (e) {
 if(e.target.value !==  ""){
   favs.push(e.target.value)
 //check if it exists  
localStorage.getItem('name') === null
 //if exists store it  
localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(favs))
   console.log(favs);
   

 } 
}




    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 rows-2 text-lg font-bold">
         {storage}
    
    </div>

<div className="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 gap-2 bg-black text-white border-white">
        {data.items
          .sort(function (a, b) {
            return  new Date (b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at) || a.stargazers_count - b.stargazers_count  
          })
          .map((d) => (
            

    <button id="btn" onClick={checkId} value={d.name}>Favorite me </button>
```

Comment: u commented the `setItem(key, value)` function?

Comment: no, just on stackoverflow to add clarity in vscode its not there.

Comment: i've added the object now and the elements that are calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling localStorage at wrong places, Even though you used `type of window !== 'undefined'`, you are already calling `const favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))` beforehand.

Assuming this is a React component. You can get the localstorage in a useEffect call.

```
const Component = () => {
     const [ fav,setFavs ] = useState([]);
     
     useEffect(() => {
           if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { //necessary because u are using nextjs
                const storage = localStorage.getItem('name');
                if (storage) {
                     setFavs(JSON.parse(storage));
                     //favs will be populated with your localStorage once, on component mount.
                }
           }
     },[])

     const checkId = (e.target.value) => {
          const value = e.target.value;
          if (!value) return;

          const newFavs = [...favs, value]
          localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(newFavs));
          setFavs(newFavs);
     }
   

     .....

     return (<pre>{ JSON.stringify(favs, null, 4)}</pre>)
}
```

#### Bonus

If you want your `favs` to be unique (values not repeated) then instead of

```
const newFavs = [...favs, value]
```

Change it to

```
const newFavs = [...new Set([...favs, value])]
```

[Reference on Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: same problem. whatever I favorite overwrites what was stored previously. So, if there were 3 elements stored  in the array and i decide to add another one, if i refresh the page only the last element i selected would be displayed.

Comment: I have updated the codes to show how checkId function should be like.

Comment: it isn't working. Also, what does 4 means here? JSON.stringify(favs, null, 4)

Comment: your codes are incomplete, and hard to figure out where your problem is, especially the part where value={d.name}. Please show more codes so we can identify the problem else it's a waste of time. At least, create a workable component.

Comment: I've added this now, it was the .map method I used.  if you look in the object it says "name". I mapped through the object and used this as the value for the event listener. I've identified the problem. The problem is, the array and local storage keep getting reset after every refresh.

Comment: As I mentioned,  as you are not showing your codes (minus important codes), we are unable to advise you why it's reset, because there might be codes that you are not showing, which are resetting your local storage. At the very least, the codes that I've shown are codes that are being used in production with no issues. It's trialed and tested.

Comment: There isn't anything else other than how i retrieve the data. I have added that in now but not sure why that would be affecting the localstorage. i've added that in now.

Comment: I see getServerSideProps, and that won't affect localStorage. Are you able to modify your code for your function/component, and make it more complete?

Comment: Happy to - modify it how? what do you mean by complete?

Comment: If it's a component, you have to start with `const MyComponent = () => {..... return (....) }`, the entire block of codes.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do **first** is setting the item in localstorage:

```
function setItem(key, item) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

now after you refresh the page you can retrieve it from the localstorage:

```
function getItem(key) {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(item);
}
```

That should be it. Also make sure you are not in inkognito mode on the browser, which might reset the storage on reloading the page.

To clarify furthermore your script would look something like this:

```
const myTestItem = 'test item';

function setItem(key, item) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
}

function getItem(key) {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(item);
}

setItem('test', myTestItem);

// after reload you can check wether it's there.
console.log(getItem('test')); // <-- just to log it to console, also u could check the application tab in chrome console and check the localstorage.
```

React Example in codesandbox:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-brook-88mpj?file=/src/App.js)

regards

Comment: how would that work in my code ? do i need to define a separate function like 'get item'?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify more.

Comment: hard to see how I can do this to my code, could you show a working example with what I have done so far.

Comment: added codesandbox for u. My answer is an example.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer

const favs = typeof window !== "undefined" ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name')): null || [];

Answer (score 0):

**This is my solution for this Question :-**

```
//you can use also  typeof window !== "undefined"  insted of  process.browser
const favs = process.browser ? localStorage.getItem('name') : null ; //necessary because u are using nextjs


useEffect(() => {
        if (process.browser) {
            setFavs(JSON.parse(favs || '""') || '')

 }
}, [favs])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer